# Count how many users have permissions to do x?

Tags: count, yii, rbac

In Yii RBAC, is it possible to get count info on how many users have permissions to do x ?

I mean, one can write a method that would:

- check all users assigned in Db,
- recursively add all the users that have parent permissions,
- and exclude repeating ids.

But are there any premade methods to do it ? Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I feel there may be a problem with getting such data because of the Yii RBAC schema construction: for instance the `authitemchild` table uses a very simple parent-child structure that makes it hard to traverse.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer.
It shouldn't be very hard to just check Count, coz you can check the authAssignment table, maybe do some SQL query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `AuthAssignment` WHERE itemname = 'PermissionXname';
```

The other things would require some thought, but not impossible, if i get it, i'd let you know.

I am not sure there are any built in methods though.

Comment: on hindsight, i'm not sure what you mean by those 3 points in your question. please elaborate if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bool.dev. In the first post, the three points are about getting also the parent permissions, before selecting assigned users. This is the hard part (traversing the permission tree). Then, you can select or count all the unique users by "DISTINCT/UNION" MySQL statements.

Comment: hey, share your rbac hierarchy if you can, then maybe it'll be easier to understand, you can give names like role1, task1, operation1 in your example and also specify the parents explicitly. better if you can share it as an image. you can upload images in the question.